# Fixed Income Portfolio

Tags: fixed-income

I am in the last 10 years of my professional career. Kids left the nest. No debts. Have some disposable income to invest towards retirement over the next 10 years before I retire.

I am looking to put together a fixed income portfolio that would protect my principal and yield 3-5% return.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: **Consider how long you will be living off this portfolio.** Is it really reasonable to move it all to a fixed-income, interest-bearing allocation *just* because of your age? If you are in the last decade of your professional career (which I take to mean that you're around 60 years old), and assuming you live in a Western nation, to a first order approximation you can *probably* expect to live for at least another 20 years. That's still a pretty long investment horizon. By all means, securing some of the capital sounds like a good plan, but do consider if you want to do that to *all* of it.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the question. I do not know if you know or not, but interest rates are extremely low currently.
Look at a 30 Year Treasury , it is yielding 228 basis points.(2.28%) and that is backed by the United States Government while the SPX or Standard and Poor's 500 Index ( stocks) is returning around 8% currently and no guarantee that it will stay that way by year end.

**If I could guarantee 3-5% for life, I would be very well off.**
- I say that because interest rates around the world are so low currently.

**Warning : All investment involves risk, but here is what I suggest you do.**

1. Search for corporations that have the highest credit rating and offer the most yield.

   - This is equivalent to taking the least amount of risk with most reward.
   - The higher the credit rating, the least likely they are too theoretically default.
   - Google to see what the credit ratings mean. (You have to do some homework, otherwise I could do it for you but,would have to charge you a fee. ;) )
2. Google will bring you here

   > According to **MarketWatch**

> - "In a sign of deteriorating credit quality,
>     Standard & Poor’s on Tuesday stripped oil giant Exxon Mobil Corp. of
>     its pristine AAA rating, leaving just two U.S. non-financial companies
>     with what is the highest possible rating on their debt."

3. I then searched for those two companies. I got one of them, Microsoft.
4. Go to this website ( FINRA Bond Center - Market Data - Morningstar is a place to find corporate bond data) [Finra: Click on Search Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsmHf.jpg)
5. Click the "Corporate bubble for type of debt instrument"
   Then in issuer name, type in "Microsoft"
6. Sort by Yield. That is what we want. I found this one

   > MICROSOFT CORP MSFT4307011 Yes Corporate Bond
   >   4.750 11/03/2055 Aaa AAA AA+
   >   114.665
   >   4.002
7. The yield is deceiving and does not set what it actually trades for. The correct yield is in bold:

   > 7/22/2016 09:44:36 7/27/2016 T 3000000
   >   115.383
   >   **3.969%**
8. That means that if you bought that specific one, it will pay you a coupon of half that yield in bold semi-annually.(every 6 months)
9. **I am going off the assumption you understand 100% on bonds work and understand the risks associated with them including, duration, convexity, and other risks including liquidity risk meaning when you are trying to sell or buy a bond because fixed income is less liquid on average than equities ( for now).**

   ---

Hope this helps!

```
**Shortened version, buy US Investment Grade Corporate Bonds**
```

Comment: Why downvoted, should be explained?

Comment: @kinkajou What?